# (Raspberry Pi 4 and Python) Raspberry Camera mode raise picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError and picamera.exc.PiCameraError

Tags: python-3, picamera, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

System: Raspberry Pi 4 model B, use external USB Logitech camera

**I'm follow the youtube tutorial but get `picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError` and`picamera.exc.PiCameraError`**

Relate discussion on other site 2021 (I didn't get their solution): "Camera issue, no idea what the problem is"
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=324702

**- The python code:**

```
from picamera import PiCamera
import time


print("= = = = = == = = = ")
camera = PiCamera()

camera.start_preview()
time.sleep(2)

camera.capture("test.jpg")
```

**- The whole output:**

```
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 456, in _init_camera
    self._camera = mo.MMALCamera()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 2279, in __init__
    super(MMALCamera, self).__init__()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 631, in __init__
    mmal_check(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 184, in mmal_check
    raise PiCameraMMALError(status, prefix)
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to create MMAL component b'vc.ril.camera': Out of memory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joy/Desktop/camera.py", line 6, in <module>
    camera = PiCamera()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 431, in __init__
    self._init_camera(camera_num, stereo_mode, stereo_decimate)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 459, in _init_camera
    raise PiCameraError(
picamera.exc.PiCameraError: Camera is not enabled. Try running 'sudo raspi-config' and ensure that the camera has been enabled.
```

---

- The youtube tutorial I follow:

How to Take Photos and Videos with Raspberry Pi Camera Module
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nx8gDSS1vO4&list=PLnjnmu-sbNYMvMiXd-y5t7fYts1N0hmuI&index=3&t=331s&ab_channel=TechWithTim

- Troubleshooting:
  (`Camera is not enabled. Try running 'sudo raspi-config' and ensure that the camera has been enabled.`
  --> The follow picture I just make sure the camera is enable, maybe because I used external usb logitech camera )

https://ibb.co/Jyxtbfv
https://ibb.co/CHrWRH1

I'm the python beginner, and first day have Raspberry Pi, stocking on camera setup, how can I fix this?

Comment: I could be wrong but I thought picamera doesn't work with USB cams. Does your tutorial say / show it does? And indeed 'enable' doesn't work for USB cams. Also be aware that picamera is not compatible with bullseye by default. You would have to switch to the 'legacy' camera stack. I suggest you check out the RPi documentation

Comment: thanks, I can keep on eye on `whether can use USB camera or Original Design Manufacturer aka raspberry pi 4's camera` cause I thougt the logic is same and just want to test before I really purchase new item, and if so, for the code part how can I improve